# preg_replace to replace '${abc}' variable

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to replace the following variable (including dollar sign and curly brackets) with my own text:

variable: `${abc}`

tried using various patterns and options but its always incorrect:

```
$body = preg_replace("/\$\{abc\}/","hello",$body);
```

any ideas how to make this work please? Changing the variable is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the double quotes around your regex to single quotes:

```
$body = preg_replace('/\$\{abc\}/',"hello",$body);
```

Otherwise the escaping doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @malta No problem. :) I've found these are the kind of mistakes syntax highlighting in your editor really helps eliminate (at least for me!). You'll notice immediately if something is escaped where it shouldn't be.

Comment: @malta Also for debugging (and learning about) regex there ain't no comparison to [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/). I can't count the hours it's saved me.